# Copying Files Using AzCopy C#

Tags: c#, azure, azcopy

I'm having an issue when copying blob containers from one storage account to another using AzCopy.

When trying to start the process I get this error Error:

Any idea why I'm having this issue?

```
    unknown command "/Source:https://pslfilestore.blob.core.windows.net/downloads" for "azcopy"
    Run 'azcopy --help' for usage.
    System.IO.StreamWriterdownloads
    unknown command "/Source:https://pslfilestore.blob.core.windows.net/downloads" for "azcopy

"
```

Please see code below

```
foreach (CloudBlobContainer items in containers)
  { 
    var AzCopyProcess = new Process();
    AzCopyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    AzCopyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    AzCopyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = strCommand;
    //pass storage account name, container and the key                           
    AzCopyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/Source:https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{items.Name} /Dest:{dayBlob.Uri}/{storageAccountName}/{items.Name} /SourceKey:{accountKey.ToString()} /DestKey:{pslFileStoreBackUpKey.ToString()} /S";


     AzCopyProcess.Start();

       StreamWriter stdOut = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
       stdOut.AutoFlush = true;
       Console.Write(stdOut);
       var output = AzCopyProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
       Console.WriteLine($"{items.Name} {output}");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be specifying `copy` command somewhere? Probably in the argument. Something like `AzCopyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"copy /Source:https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{items.Name} /Dest:{dayBlob.Uri}/{storageAccountName}/{items.Name} /SourceKey:{accountKey.ToString()} /DestKey:{pslFileStoreBackUpKey.ToString()} /S";
`

Comment: What version of AzCopy are you using? AzCopy V8 and V10 use completely different parameters.

Comment: @Craig Gallagher - do you get failed and success result properly in standard output stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error report, you are using the AzCopy V10 however your code is in V8 format. I think this is the problem.

In V10 the copy usage should be: `azcopy copy [source] [destination] [flags]`.

And the copy container syntax should be: `azcopy cp "https://<source-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>" "https://<destination-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>" --recursive`.

For more details you could refer to this doc: [Transfer data with AzCopy and Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json). Or you could use like `azure cp --help` to get the details.

Comment: That's it mate. Thank you very much